# I can't access my virtualhost with ServerName

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have created virtual host addind code below to the end of config file of apache.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin jan@novak.cz
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName Name_of_server
    ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/log.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I need to access it with adress http://Name_of_server but web borowser can't find "Name_of_server", localhost is still working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may need to edit your hosts config under the `c:\windows\system32\driver\etc\hosts` or you need to access your domain name provider to point to the IP address of your server if you have a static IP.